# How to determine if a post was last edited in the Visual Editor

Tags: posts, visual-editor, html-editor

Is there any way to determine whether a post was last edited using the Visual or HTML editor? Perhaps by hooking into an action?

Answer (score 1):

`wp_default_editor();` will tell you the default editor - the last editor used. You can hook into the update/save post action and store this for the current post in the options array or somewhere similar. It's used in `wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php` to define the default editor when loading TinyMCE in the post editor.